# How to perform minimum splits to satisfy special set ordering?

Tags: algorithm, set

I'm trying to create an algorithm to solve the following problem: 
[image: Updated image of problem]

Input is an unsorted list of sets containing pairs (key, value) of ints. The first of each pair is positive and unique within the set.
I want to find an algorithm to split the input sets so the sets can be ordered such that for each key the value is nondecreasing in the set order.

There is a trival solution which is to split the sets into each individual value and sort them, I'd like something more efficient in terms of the number of sets which are split.

Are there any similar problems you have encountered and/or techniques you can suggest?
Does the optimal (minimum number of splits) solution sound like it is possible in polynomial time?

---

Edit: In the example the "<=" operator indicates a constraint on the sets as a whole whereby for each key value (100, 101, 102) the corresponding values are equal to or greater than the values in previous sets (or omitted from the set). I.e extracting the values for each key using the order from the output sets gives:

- Key 100 {0, 1}
- Key 101 {2, 3}
- Key 102 {10, 15}

Comment: Can you please precise your problem? In your image, I can't figure out why b has to be split.

Comment: @Bentoy13 Thanks, yes set b needs split because its value for key 100 is less than that for set a, but its value for key 101 is greater than that for set a. So it needs split to satisfy the global constraint. And i got the order of the result wrong in my image, I'll fix it..

Comment: What do you mean by, the *first*of each pair is positive and unique?

Comment: @Picarus Sorry, wasn't sure how to best explain it... essentially the sets contain key value pairs, like a dictionary data structure. So for example set a in the example could not have (100, 0) added to it as the first items of the pairs must be unique within the set. There is no constraint on the second items (values) within a set.

Comment: if your restriction is for the sequence to be nondecreasing, split will not help. I think you should clarify more.

Comment: Maybe nondecreasing isn't the right term, sorry... The constraint is that for each possible key (100, 101, 102 in the example) the sets must be capable of being ordered such that the values corresponding to the key are either not present, equal or greater than the values in the preceding sets. So the input data in the example cannot satisfy this constrain without being split, and can satisfy it after being split.

Comment: Are you looking for a proven optimal solution (i.e. minimal number of splits), or is a heuristic to reduce the number of interest as well?

Comment: “Are there any similar problems you have encountered”: I saw something similar while reconstructing a consistent history from CVS commits. Your keys would be path names, your values revision numbers. Commits with the same message and sufficiently close commit dates would form a set. In that case I ended up identifying the next set (using minimal timestamp), choosing all permissible elements from it (i.e. those which don't depend on a revision that isn't part of my history yet) and adding those to the history. Similar setup, but perhaps very different optimality goals.

Comment: @MvG I don't need a proven optimum solution, I'm assuming that might be quite tricky. A heursitic to identify a set to split in a greedy style may be enough, but I was struggling with how to make one "good enough".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A*

**I propose using [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) to find an optimal solution.** Build the order of split sets incrementally from left to right, minimizing the number of sets required to achieve this.

A* visits *states* based on some *heuristic* estimate of the total cost. I propose that a *state* is described by the totality of all the pairs already included in the order as we have it so far. If all values for every key are different, then you can represent this information rather concisely by simply storing the last value for each key. Otherwise you'll have to somehow take care of equal values, so you know which ones were already included and which ones were not. For every state you maintain some representation of the best order leading to it, but that may get updated along the way while the state remains the same.

The *heuristic* should be an estimate of the total cost of the path from the beginning through the current state to the goal. It may be too low, but must never be too high. In our case, the heuristic should count the number of (possibly split) sets included in the order so far, and add to that the number of (unsplit) sets still waiting for insertion. As the remaining sets may need splitting, this might be too low, but as you can never have less sets than those still waiting for insertion, it is a suitable heuristic.

Now you have some priority queue of states, ordered by the value of this heuristic. You extract minimal items from it, and know that the moment you extract a state from the queue, the cost up to that state can not decrease any more, so the path up to that state is optimal. Now you examine what other states can be reached from this: which other pairs can be next in the order of split sets? For each remaining set which has pairs that are ready to be included, you create a new subsequent state, taking all the pairs from the set which are ready. The cost so far increases by one. If you manage to take a whole set, without splitting, then the extimate for the remaining cost decreases by one.

For this new state, you check whether it is already persent in your priority queue. If it is, and its previous cost was higher than the one just computed, then you update its cost, and the optimal path leading to it. Make sure the priority key changes its position accordingly (“decrease key”). If the state wasn't present in the queue before, then add it to the queue.

## Dijkstra

Come to think of it, this is the same as running [Dijkstra's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) with the number of splits as cost. And as each edge has either cost zero or cost one, you can implement this even easier, without any priority queue at all. Instead, you can use two sets, called `S₀` and `S₁`, where all elements from S₀ require the same number of splits, and all elements from S₁ require one more split. Roughly sketched in pseudocode:

```
S₀ = ∅ (empty set)
S₁ = ∅
add initial state (no pairs added yet, all sets remain to be added) to S₀
while True
    while (S₀ ≠ ∅)
        x = take and remove any element from zero
        if x is the target state (all pairs included in the order) then
            return the path information associated with it
        for (r: those sets which remain to be added in state x)
            if we can take r as a whole then
                let y be the state obtained by taking r as the next set in the order
                if y is in S₁, remove it
                add y to S₀
            else if we can add only some elements from r then
                let y bet the state obtained by taking as many elements from r as possible
                if y is not in S₀, add it to S₁
    S₀ = S₁
    S₁ = ∅
```